# Adding a colorbar outside an image without shrinking it

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colorbar, imshow

I'm trying to plot a 3x3 subplots, the first line using imshow, and second and third are regular graphs. All the 3x3 plots share the same x-axis, so it's really important that they will be perfectly aligned (I didn't use sharey=true because I wanted the y-ticks). I was able to put the graphs legends outside the figure in the right (the legend is the same legend for the whole 3 figures in the same row) by using:

```
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

But I couldn't find how to put the colorbar of the first row above them, without shrinking the third plot in the first row. I was trying to use "make_axes_locatable":

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
divider = make_axes_locatable(powers_ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=1)
plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
```

Or "inset_axes":

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes
axins = inset_axes(powers_ax, width="10%", height="100%", loc=5,
                   bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0, 1, 1), bbox_transform=powers_ax.transAxes)
plt.colorbar(im, cax=axins)
```

Or even this trick:

```
fig.colorbar(im2, ax=ax[0, :].ravel().tolist(), location='right', shrink=0.6)
```

But nothing gave me the result I watned.
Any ideas?

*** EDIT ***

As @ImportanceOfBeingErnest suggested, the solution was tweaking the first parameter in the bbox_to_anchor (from 0.5 to 1.15 in this case):

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes
axins = inset_axes(powers_ax, width="5%", height="100%", loc=5,
                   bbox_to_anchor=(1.15, 0, 1, 1), bbox_transform=powers_ax.transAxes)
plt.colorbar(im2, cax=axins)
```

[image]

Comment: First and third options cannot work, because indeed they take portions of the axes space to place the colorbar. The second option looks promising. I think you just got the parameters wrong? Try `1.1` instead of `0.5`. if the problem persists, a [mcve] would be nice, such that one can test what goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that was the solution!